# How do I use pandas.shift() without losing data?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to shift certain rows in a .csv down without losing the last row. Say if you use `df.shift(1)`, it will return the shifted dataframe, removing the last row of data. What I'm wanting is it to shift without losing the last row of data.

Original (data):

```
example1,example1
example2,example2
example3,example3
```

What happens after `data.shift(1)`:

```
NaN,NaN
example1,example1
example2,example2
```

What I would like:

```
NaN,NaN
example1,example1
example2,example2
example3,example3
```

Maybe creating a row on the end filled with `NaN` would fix this? (I don't know how to fill cells with `NaN`).

Here is my actual code where I am selecting **certain** rows:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('path/test.csv', header=False,
yes = data.iloc[2:3].shift(1)
print(yes)
```

output:

```
NaN,NaN
example2,example2
```

Comment: Could you just concatenate with a dataframe of na values? `pd.concat(na_df, df)`?

Comment: I could i guess but that seems like a really inefficient way to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
          0         1
0  example1  example1
1  example2  example2
2  example3  example3
```

Doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Version 1:
df.index += 1
df.loc[0] = np.nan
df = df.sort_index()

# Version 2:
df.loc[-1] = np.nan
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
          0         1
0       NaN       NaN
1  example1  example1
2  example2  example2
3  example3  example3
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the approach of adding a row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['example1','example1'],['example2','example2'],['example3','example3']])
row = ['blank','blank']

df.loc[len(df)] = row
```

Gives:

```
    0   1
0   example1    example1
1   example2    example2
2   example3    example3
3   blank   blank
```

Comment: I'd just do `df.loc[len(df)] = np.nan`